# OnDemand WebJob fails after a few minutes

Tags: c#, azure, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

I just created simple web job that just writes something to console. This job is supposed to run on demand so when I published it to Azure, I set it to run on demand.

When I run it, it works fine but after a few minutes it fails with the following message.

> [12/07/2015 18:07:20 > f78915: ERR ] Command 'cmd /c TestJob.exe' was
>   aborted due to no output nor CPU activity for 121 seconds. You can
>   increase the SCM_COMMAND_IDLE_TIMEOUT app setting (or
>   WEBJOBS_IDLE_TIMEOUT if this is a WebJob) if needed. cmd /c
>   TestJob.exe [12/07/2015 18:07:20 > f78915: SYS INFO] Status changed to
>   Failed

Here's what follows that error:

> [12/07/2015 18:07:20 > f78915: SYS ERR ] System.AggregateException:
>   One or more errors occurred. --->
>   Kudu.Core.Infrastructure.CommandLineException: Command 'cmd /c
>   TestJob.exe' was aborted due to no output nor CPU activity for 121
>   seconds. You can increase the SCM_COMMAND_IDLE_TIMEOUT app setting (or
>   WEBJOBS_IDLE_TIMEOUT if this is a WebJob) if needed. cmd /c
>   TestJob.exe    at
>   Kudu.Core.Infrastructure.IdleManager.WaitForExit(IProcess process)
>   at Kudu.Core.Infrastructure.ProcessExtensions.d__a.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Kudu.Core.Infrastructure.Executable.d__1d.MoveNext()
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean
>   includeTaskCanceledExceptions)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean
>   waitCompletionNotification)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()    at
>   Kudu.Core.Infrastructure.Executable.ExecuteInternal(ITracer tracer,
>   Func`2 onWriteOutput, Func`2 onWriteError, Encoding encoding, String
>   arguments, Object[] args)    at
>   Kudu.Core.Infrastructure.Executable.ExecuteReturnExitCode(ITracer
>   tracer, Action`1 onWriteOutput, Action`1 onWriteError, String
>   arguments, Object[] args)    at
>   Kudu.Core.Jobs.BaseJobRunner.RunJobInstance(JobBase job, IJobLogger
>   logger, String runId, String trigger, Int32 port)
>   ---> (Inner Exception #0) ExitCode: -1, Output: Command 'cmd /c TestJob.exe' was aborted due to no output nor CPU activity for 121
>   seconds. You can increase the SCM_COMMAND_IDLE_TIMEOUT app setting (or
>   WEBJOBS_IDLE_TIMEOUT if this is a WebJob) if needed., Error: Command
>   'cmd /c TestJob.exe' was aborted due to no output nor CPU activity for
>   121 seconds. You can increase the SCM_COMMAND_IDLE_TIMEOUT app setting
>   (or WEBJOBS_IDLE_TIMEOUT if this is a WebJob) if needed.,
>   Kudu.Core.Infrastructure.CommandLineException: Command 'cmd /c
>   TestJob.exe' was aborted due to no output nor CPU activity for 121
>   seconds. You can increase the SCM_COMMAND_IDLE_TIMEOUT app setting (or
>   WEBJOBS_IDLE_TIMEOUT if this is a WebJob) if needed. cmd /c
>   TestJob.exe    at
>   Kudu.Core.Infrastructure.IdleManager.WaitForExit(IProcess process)
>   at Kudu.Core.Infrastructure.ProcessExtensions.d__a.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Kudu.Core.Infrastructure.Executable.d__1d.MoveNext()<---

Here's the entire code for this web job.

```
static void Main()
        {
            var host = new JobHost();
            Console.Out.WriteLine("Testing the test job...");
            host.RunAndBlock();
        }
```

I understand that it fails because there's no activity but it's supposed to be a job that runs on demand. Where am I making a mistake?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The fact that it's a job that runs on demand has nothing to do with the error. It's just a job that starts when you tell it to.

Jobs that do not do anything for a period of time (121 seconds according to what you got) will abort.

Comment: Do they abort with a failure message? Is there a way to put the job to sleep a bit more gracefully?

Comment: From the looks of it, your job does nothing but print to the console. So the call to `host.RunAndBlock();` is unnecessary; that line is used for continuous webjobs.

Comment: That makes sense! Thank you.